# What's the difference between .closest() and .parents('selector')?

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

What's the difference between these? Is one more efficient than the other? I'm a little bit confused to why they both exist. Say I have this markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td><span class='toggle'>Toggle</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td><span class='toggle'>Toggle</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>..</td>
        <td><span class='toggle'>Toggle</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

From the `<span>` tags I could use  *either* `$(this).closest('tr');` or `$(this).parents('tr');` to access the parent/closest `<tr>` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) returns the immediate parents (one for each element in the caller object) or nothing if the parent does not match the selector. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) returns the closest ancestor matching ancestor for each element (which can be the original element). The third similar function, [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), returns all matching ancestors (not including the element itself).

Generally, `closest` is more resistant to refactoring the HTML code than `parent`, if you choose the selector sensibly.

Answer (score 18):

*(Note: The question was edited the day after being asked, changing the question from about `parent` to being about `parents` [note the plural]. Which kind of makes a difference!)*

Re your **original** question about `parent` (singular) vs. `closest`: [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) only ever goes one level up. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) starts with the current element (not just the parent) and keeps searching through ancestors until it finds a match (or runs out of ancestors).

Re your updated **question** about `parents` (plural) vs. `closest`: There are two differences:

1. Whether the current element is considered (it is with `closest`, it is not with [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents)).
2. Whether the search stops with the first match (it does with `closest`, it doesn't with `parents`).

From your **original** question:

> From the  tags I could use either $(this).closest('tr'); or $(this).parent('tr');

No, actually. `$(this).parent('tr');` would return an empty jQuery object, because the parent of the `span` doesn't match the selector.

From your **updated** question:

> From the  tags I could use either $(this).closest('tr'); or $(this).parents('tr');

You could, *provided* that your `tr` isn't also within another `tr` (e.g., a table containing a table). If that's the case, you'll get the same result. But if you have a table within a table, with `parents` you'll get multiple `tr`s (**all** of the ancestor `tr` elements).

Consider this structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Testing <span>1 2 3</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If we hook `click` on the `span`, this is what we get back from the three relevant methods:

- `$(this).parent('div')` - Empty jQuery object, the parent of the `span` is not a `div`.
- `$(this).parents('div')` - jQuery object with **two** `div`s in it, the "inner" and "wrapper" divs (in that order).
- `$(this).closest('div')` - jQuery object with **one** `div` in it, the "inner" one.

Here's the result if we hook `click` on the `span` and use `span` as the selector:

- `$(this).parent('span')` - Empty jQuery object, the parent of the `span` is not a `span`.
- `$(this).parents('span')` - Empty jQuery object, the `span` has no ancestor `span`s.
- `$(this).closest('span')` - jQuery object with the `span` that was clicked.

Comment: @user1534664: :-) I don't know. But thanks for flagging it up, as I notice the question had been edited after I answered it, in a way that required a change to the answer. Very significant change in the question between the day it was asked and the next day when it was edited.

Comment: This explains exactly how parent/parents/closet works different from the others,thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was very clear. And how jquery handles descendants in this case of `closest()` ? Is it same  ?

Comment: @SanKrish: `closest` doesn't look at descendants at all, just the elements in the set you call it on and their ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

`.parent()` only goes up one level, while `closest()` includes the current element, and all parents.

Example (selecting from the bottom `div`, `x` = matched elements):

```
             parent()  parent('body')   .closest('div')  .parents('div')
body     
   div                                                       x
      div       x        <nothing>                           x
this-->   div                                x
```