# Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions

Tags: jquery

I have been using jQuery for a while. I wanted to use the `parent()` selector. I also came up with the `closest()` selector. Could not find any difference between them. Is there any? If yes, what?

What is the difference between `parent()`, `parents()` and `closest()`?

Comment: parent::::travels 1 step back to parent....::::parents::: gives a list of all parents....::::closest::: travels back through siblings till it finds the condition and return only the first. All these can be modified with additional selectors

Answer (score 195, accepted):

> [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) selects the first element that matches the selector, up
>   from the DOM tree. Begins from the current element and travels up.
>
> [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) selects one element up (single level up) the DOM tree.
>
> [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method is similar to [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) but selects all the
>   matching elements up the DOM tree. Begins from the parent element and travels up.

Answer (score 205):

from http://api.jquery.com/closest/

> The **.parents()** and **.closest()** methods are similar in that they both
> traverse up the DOM tree. The differences between the two, though
> subtle, are significant:
>
> ***.closest()***
>
> - Begins with the current element
> - Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied
>   selector
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element
>
> ***.parents()***
>
> - Begins with the parent element
> - Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each
>   ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that
>   collection based on a selector if one is supplied
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero, one, or multiple elements
>
> ***.parent()***
>
> - Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .parent() method allows us to search through the parents of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements.
>
> ***Note:*** *The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
> latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also,
> $("html").parent() method returns a set containing document whereas
> $("html").parents() returns an empty set.*

Here are related threads:

- [What's the difference between .closest() and .parents('selector')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975985/whats-the-difference-between-closest-and-parentsselector)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200805/149206

Comment: He actually asked about parent(), not parents().

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Please check the answer again with `Note`.

Comment: `The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also, $("html").parent() method returns a set containing document whereas $("html").parents() returns an empty set.`

Comment: @ScubaSteve, yeah, but the parents() question is more interesting.

Answer (score 21):

The differences between the two, though subtle, are significant:

> [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> - Begins with the current element
> - Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element
>
> [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
>
> - Begins with the parent element
> - Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied
> - The returned jQuery object contains zero, one, or multiple elements

From jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: i think your describing .parents() here

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between both `$(this).closest('div')` and `$(this).parents('div').eq(0)`

Basically `closest` start matching element from the current element whereas `parents` start matching elements from parent (one level above the current element)

See http://jsfiddle.net/imrankabir/c1jhocre/1/

Answer (score -1):

`$(this).closest('div')` is same as `$(this).parents('div').eq(0)`.

Comment: Not quite, if $(this) is also a div.

Answer (score -1):

`parent()` method returns the direct parent element of the selected one. This method only traverse a **single** level up the DOM tree.

`parents()` method allows us to search through the **ancestors** of these elements in the DOM tree. Begin from given selector and move up.

```
The **.parents()** and **.parent()** methods are almost similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also, **$( "html" ).parent()** method returns a set containing document whereas **$( "html" ).parents()** returns an empty set.

[closest()][3]method returns the first ancestor of the selected element.An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on.

This method traverse upwards from the current element, all the way up to the document's root element (<html>), to find the first ancestor of DOM elements.

According to docs:

**closest()** method is similar to **parents()**, in that they both traverse up the DOM tree. The differences are as follows:

**closest()**

Begins with the current element
Travels up the DOM tree and returns the first (single) ancestor that matches the passed expression
The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element

**parents()**

Begins with the parent element
Travels up the DOM tree and returns all ancestors that matches the passed expression
The returned jQuery object contains zero or more than one element
```