# Jquery select containing div of target

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="txtTitle">Title</label>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="text-holder"> <span class="ico-error"></span><span class="text"> <input id="txtTitle"
     runat="server" type="text" value="" /></span>  <span class="t-l">
     </span><span class="b-l"></span><span class="t-r"></span><span class="b-r"></span> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following html.  I am planning on doing some Jquery validation on the input box.  If this is invalid I want to add the error class to the div

```
        var isValid = true;
        var errorMessage = '';
        if ($('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>').val() == '') {
            $('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>').parent().parent().parent(".row").addClass("error");
            isValid = false;
            errorMessage += "Firstname is required\n";
        }
        return isValid;
```

I've tried to target the parent but see that this div is further up the parent heirachy. so tried to select up the heirachy with more parent tags, but think I am straying well off course from understanding the correct way to target the div.

Comment: did any of the answers below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

> **Description**: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
var isValid = true;
var errorMessage = '';
var $this = $('#<%=txtTitle.ClientID %>');

if ($this.val() == '') {
    $this.closest(".row").addClass("error");
    isValid = false;
    errorMessage += "Firstname is required\n";
}
return isValid;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to look up the tree, use the [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method and pass it the class of your containing div, i.e.: `.parents('.row')`

Comment: I think `closest()` is what is needed in this instance. I suggest reviewing the docs or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function) to understand the differences between `closest()` and `parents()`.

Comment: Both will work. Since we know there is only one containing element up the chain, they end up doing the same thing.

Comment: That's incorrect. Since he's using `row` as a class, it's reasonable to think that there are more rows. He only want's the closest row, not all the rows above. This is not the correct method.

Comment: My answer is correct according to the original code and question. Both methods work. That's the beauty of jQuery.