# Is There Any Way To Select This Parent?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="chatbox-window">
    <div class="chatbox-title">
        <div class="chatbox-username"></div><div class="chatbox-close"><span class="chatbox-close-button"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="chatbox-content"><div class="chatbox-msg"></div></div>
    <div id="chatbox-posting"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
    $(".chatbox-close-button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent(".chatbox-close").parent(".chatbox-title").parent(".chatbox-window").remove();
    });
```

---

Below, i use:

```
$(this).parent(".chatbox-close").parent(".chatbox-title").parent(".chatbox-window") to get the ".chatbox-window"
```

But:

Are there shorter ways to get the `.chatbox-window`

Ps. In case of not changing the `HTML` code.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: If you're trying to decide between `closest()` or `parents()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function

Answer (score 1):

use `parents()`

#### [**Official Document**](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

**Description:** Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(this).parents(".chatbox-window").remove();
```

Comment: I think this will work if change span -> div.
Any way, thanks :)

Comment: @InOrderToLive it does not matter as long as you just define class name..if you specify .parents("div.chatbox-window") then it will look for div with having class that you have declared..

Answer (score 0):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$('.chatbox-close-button').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.chatbox-window').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kLthS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery closest(). Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('.chatbox-window').remove()
```