# Not able to capture parent object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to capture the `id` attribute on the parent here, and It returns as `undefined`

```
<table>
  <tr id="1343">
    <td><span class="hi">Hi</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var $id = $(".hi").parent("tr").attr("id");
alert($id);
```

I thought I was using it right, but I guess not, anyone know why it won't give me the value I'm trying to get?

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AsDY6/

Comment: So many answers, which one to use, lol.

Comment: If I had a say, as much as I would love the rep points for myself, I would choose clav's answer.  It gives the most succinct explanation and is backed up by a fiddle and a performance test. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `parents` instead of `parent` on your row selector.

```
var $id = $(".hi").parents("tr").attr("id");
```

As noted by others `closest` will also work. The difference is that `parents` will get all parent elements that match the selector. So if you had nested tables you would probably want to use `closest` because `parents` would get all parent table rows. If I know the DOM will always only have one parent matching the selector, I tend to prefer `parents` for performance reasons because `parents` is faster according to performance tests like [this one](http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/2).

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AsDY6/1/).

Comment: As this test indicates (http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/32) it's also faster to use `.parents()` than it is to use `.parents().first()` and both are faster than `.closest()` -- a bit of a surprise.  I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

`.parent()` returns the immediate parent, which in this case is the td

Use closest instead.   `$id = $(".hi").closest("tr").attr("id");`

Answer (score 1):

Try `.closest('tr')` or `.parents('tr')` instead of `.parent('tr');`.

`.parent()` will only go up one level, whereas `.closest()` will continue to climb up the DOM until it finds a match and `.parents()` will search up to the root ancestor.  (You can also chain `.first()` to `.parents()` (e.g., `.parents().first()`) so that it returns only the first match.)

See [Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function) for more information about the different methods.  And check out these [performance comparisons](http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/32) between the three proposed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var $id = $(".hi").parent("tr").attr("id");
```

TOO

```
var $id = $(".hi").parents("tr").first().attr("id");
```

OR

```
var $id = $(".hi").closest("tr").attr("id");
```

### ***WHY***

The answer is simple. The tag `<tr>` is not the parent of `.hi`. `.hi`'s parent is actually the `<td>` it resides in. Thus you can use `.parents` instead. However, this could grab one too many, so make sure to use something like [.first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) if you only want the First parent fitting that description.

OR

Use jQuery's [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method which is supposed to do about the same thing as `.parents('selector').first()`

Answer (score -1):

Reference parent of parent

Use this code:

```
var $id = $(".hi").parent().parent().attr("id");
```

It's work!

Comment: If the class "hi" gets added to a different element, one that isn't a child of the TD, your code breaks, so it is not a very robust solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
   var $id = $(".hi").parent("td").parent('tr').attr("id");
  alert($id);
```