# IE 8, jQuery 1.7.1 $(element).parents(selector) returns siblings also

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, parents

I have a form with this layout:

```
<div class='detail'>
    <div>
        <input type='button' class='save' />
    </div>
</div>
<div class='detail'>
    <div>
        <input type='button' class='save' />
    </div>
</div>
<div class='detail'>
    <div>
        <input type='button' class='save' />
    </div>
</div>
```

When `$(".save").click()` is triggered. I call `$(this).parents(".detail")`

For IE, this is what happens:
- The parent `<div class='detail'>` is selected as well as the previous `<div class='detail'>` siblings.

For FF, this is what happens:
- Only the parent `<div class='detail'>` is returned.

The correct functionality I'm looking for is what FF is doing.

May I know how to do a work-around for IE.

Thank you.

EDIT:
This is the click event handler:

```
$(".product_details .button_save_draft").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parents(".product_details").length);
});
```

Comment: What if you check another jquery version?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: try using `.closest('.detail')` instead of `.parents(".detail")`

Comment: @ArunPJohny `.closest(".detail")` works for me. Thanks. I'm still wondering why `.parents(".detail")` does not work for IE.

Comment: @zerkms I tried changing the jquery version to jquery 1.10.2 with jquery migrate 1.2.1 and it still functions the same way for IE.

Comment: @Jantoy can you recheck your html markup to see how it is structured

Comment: @ArunPJohny I checked and it's the way I mentioned above. Does it help if I mention that the other .detail divs are hidden?

Comment: @Jantoy still it does not make any sense, if the markup is as you have described above it should be fine

Comment: @Jantoy another question, is there any other parent with the class `detail`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I know, it's really odd. I can' test it in jsFiddle too because my development PC does not have access to the internet and my research PC uses IE 10. If change the compatibility view to IE8 and IE8 Standards mode, jsFiddle won't load properly. I checked and double-checked the mark-up, There is no other parent element with class `detail`. Anyway, I'll use `.closest()` for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any idea why the above is working as described above, but as a solution probably you need to look at [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(".product_details .button_save_draft").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest(".product_details").length);
});
```

Also see the [difference between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function)

Comment: Thanks Arun! Now, I have to check all my code that used `.parents()` and see if they run smoothly if I change them to `.closest()`. Wish me luck