# How to pick up data- * in the parent from the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<header data-ride="share">
 <div class="child__one">
   <div class="child__two">
     <div class="child__three"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Is possible to catch the header tag from the child__three??

For example:

```
var parent = $('.child__three').parents('[data-ride="share"]');
```

This won't work at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var parent = $('.child__three').closest('[data-ride="share"]');
```

The problem with [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) is it can return multiple objects.

See [Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-functions)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cayqos9t/1/)

Comment: Can you please show me this in a working fiddle? Because i already try use the closest and the console.log(parent) will show ->   [div.child__three, context: div.child__three]

Comment: but if i use the closest('[data-ride]'); then will work.. hm!

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, even if you try var parent = $('.child__three').parents('[data-ride="share"]'); from your question, it works. One sec, I will update my fiddle to show you

Comment: That's so weird.. well.. i'm going to accept your answer because is working in your code, but in mine is not. I'm using prototype pattern and i'm not using the $('.child__three'), i'm using the this keyword (but in the context it means the same thing).. could this causing some problem??

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, no you dont have to accept my answer. I want to help. Can you post some of the relevant prototype code?

Comment: Yes, i can. Just give me a second.

Comment: Can you put the code surrounding the 'this' keyword you are using? Even if I cant help, maybe somebody else will

Comment: http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/rVLEPE there it is @AmmarCSE, the this.parent will be the child and not the parent.

Comment: did you see? @AmmarCSE

Comment: ok :).. This doesn't make much sense i think, i already try to solve with a co-worker but we don't have any idea..

Comment: ok, found the problem. You have two attributes for that element with 'data-ride'. Looking for a solution

Comment: If you look here, it works becuase I changed the order of the 'data-ride' attributes. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPRzzg  Do you see the problem?

Comment: i get that know.. i have several data-rides with several purposes in my code, its like plugins, but i'm going to change everything :). Thanks for the help!!!