# How to remove script tag from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to remove script tag from Html Code using JavaScript.
Here is the HTML Code :

```
<script type='text/x-template-handlebars' id='carousel_ui_buttons_next-nav_next'>
<button class="next nav" asg-button>{{{button_text}}}</button>
</script>
```

I want to remove script tag so the remaining part would be html only.
I mean code should be changed inside browser.

Comment: Are you asking for the HTML inside of the `<script>` tag to remain in place, or for the entire block to be removed?

Comment: When do you need the script tag to be removed? When the document loads? When a button is clicked? Please explain in more detail :)

Comment: Why do you need the script tag to be removed?

Comment: I just wanna remove <script> tag entire HTML should stay at the place.

Comment: @CodyMan What HTML, the rest of the HTML you haven't posted or the HTML inside of the <script> tag in your question?

Comment: I mean the <button> tag should stay at the same place. but script tags should be removed.

Comment: The content of the script element is invalid script. Voting to close as unclear what the OP is asking. Also, there are many similar questions that the OP could leverage.

Comment: What's not clear? everything is fine there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your `<script>` tag is invalid Javascript, but here is one possible way of achieving what you are after:

```
// Function to convert an HTML string to a DOM element
String.prototype.toDOM = function () {
    var d = document,
        i,
        a = d.createElement('div'),
        b = d.createDocumentFragment();
    a.innerHTML = this;
    while (i = a.firstChild) {
        b.appendChild(i);
    }
    return b;
};

// The <script> we wish to replace
var st = document.getElementById('carousel_ui_buttons_next-nav_next');

// Replace it with the <button> that is inside of it
st.parentNode.replaceChild(st.innerHTML.trim().toDOM(), st);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for great answer.

Answer (score 2):

it would be better if you provided us with the code you currently have to help you understand what happened rather than using the code copy/paste ,anyway to fire the js code you first decide when you want it to kick in

> when the page finish loading ?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#carousel_ui_buttons_next-nav_next').remove();
});
```

> or when the page is ready

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#carousel_ui_buttons_next-nav_next').remove();
});
```

> or if you prefer you can make it as a function and call it as much as
>   you want instead of repeating the same code over and over everywhere

```
function hideScript() {
    $('#carousel_ui_buttons_next-nav_next').remove();
});
// then use it like //
$(document).ready(function($) {
    hideScript();
});
```

the above code use JQuery which is much easier than vanilla js to understand and to work with.

Comment: This is only the case if the OP wants to remove the entire block. I believe they may be asking for the HTML inside of the `<script>` tag to remain in place. I have added a comment to the OP to clarify.

Comment: I just wanna remove  <script> tag entire HTML should stay at the place.

Comment: @CodyMan so you mean when you click the button the script tag should be removed ?

Comment: Nope! I mean when the site loads the script tag should be removed but the content inside that should stay there.

Comment: All because, I am unable to perform click function inside that script tag.

Comment: @CodyMan actually putting the btn inside the script tag is wrong from the beginning, you should try a different approach.

Comment: Yeah! I know but that's not my code, That's why i am stuck up.
I just require to remove that script tag so i will be able to click on that button.

Comment: it will never work as its invalid as @RobG said, but anyway as an answer to ur question check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91988/discussion-between-codyman-and-ctf0).