# JQuery add class if selected for each input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently use the following jQuery code to add a class if the input type checkbox is checked. But it adds the class to all elements even if they are not checked.

How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon1">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[1]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon2">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[2]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox product-option">
    <label for="addon3">
        <span class="product-option-text">
            <input class="checkbox-row" type="checkbox" name="addons[3]" id="addon1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
            <span class="text">Text</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
            $('div.checkbox.product-option').addClass("selected"); 
        else 
            $('div.checkbox.product-option').removeClass("selected");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "also the ones that are not checked" - and how does `$('div.checkbox.product-option')` signify only the checked elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`product-option` is the parent container of checkbox. To get the current `product-option`, you need to use `.closest(".product-option")`  selector

```
jQuery(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest(".product-option").addClass("selected");
  else
    $(this).closest(".product-option").removeClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `.closest` instead.

You are passing selector, hence its applying changes to all element that satisfies it. Try to make it relative to `this`

```
$(this).closest('div.checkbox.product-option').addClass("selected");
```

You can even use `.parent()`:

```
$(this).parent().addClass("selected");
```

You can refer following post for more information: [Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-parents-and-closest-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('div.checkbox.product-option').addClass("selected");` which will select all the elements with that class just use `this` and find the checkboxes closest ancestor with that class.

```
jQuery(".checkbox-row").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        $(this).closest('div.checkbox.product-option').addClass("selected"); 
    else 
        $(this).closest('div.checkbox.product-option').removeClass("selected");
});
```