# jQuery : Get first closest "parent" by type?

Tags: jquery, parent-child, closest

I need to get the `id` of the first closest (nearest) `li` parent element when i click on `a` element.

```
<ul>
    <li id="wrong1">
        <ul>
          <li id="p1">
            <a href="" class='btn'></a>
          </li>
          <li id="p2">
            <a href="" class='btn'>Click here!</a>
          </li>
          <li id="p3">
            <a href="" class='btn'></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="wrong2"></li>
</ul>
```

When i clicked on `Click here!`, i'm supposed to get `li#p2` element.

I used:

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e) {
    var GotIt = $(this).parents().find('li').attr('id');
});
```

But apparently it didn't work. I also tried `closest()` and also the same outcome.

How to get the element properly please?

Comment: Did you try `closest("li")` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-parents-and-closest-functions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should write your script as

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e) {
    var GotIt = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
});
```

because "li" is the direct parent of your "a" element, so u can also use like

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e) {
    var GotIt = $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Attention!

Although the given answers work in this (your) case, they are wrong - regarding the question:

"the **closest parent** with [what ever]"

Correct is

```
$element.parent().closest([what ever])
```

`closest()` includes the element itself and as long it is not [what ever], too, the script works fine, but …

This is a slumbering error in many scripts, that shows up after DOM - design changes later in development.

The docs say for `closest()`:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector **by testing the element itself** and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

(bold from me)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest(type)`, ie:

```
$('a.btn').click(function(e) {
    var li = $(this).closest("li");
    alert(li.attr("id"))
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f14vjLmc/

Answer (score 3):

try this [closest() JQuery Method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)