# How to get parent element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

A bit confused about how to target the following input with name client id, Tried lots of things but nothing worked !

So here I am :

```
<td class="main_contact">
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="45">
    <label class="switch">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>    
</td>
```

Here is what I tried as :

```
$('.switch input').on('change',function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var parent_el = $(this).parents().eq(1).closest('input[name="client_id"]').val();
        // var client_id = $(parent_el[0]+' input[name="client_id"]').val();
        console.log(parent_el);
    } else {
        alert('Its UNCHECKED');
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** I want to get the value of input with name `client_id` while referencing it from the `$(this)` element so that I get only the current changed element input data not the data of every input there is?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parents, http://api.jquery.com/parent or or http://api.jquery.com/closest. Either way, I suggest you read the jQuery documentation for simple queries like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write `.parent('selector')`, but in this case, you want the parent without condition and then get a sibling. (You can use `.siblings('selector')` for that)

```js
$('.switch input').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var parentVal = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name="client_id"]').val();
    console.log(parentVal);
  } else {
    alert('Its UNCHECKED');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="main_contact">
  <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="45">
  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</td>
```

Comment: You got it. Thumbs up ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$(this).closest('.main_contact').find('[name="client_id"]').val();
```

[Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-parents-and-closest-functions)

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your answer !