# Make dynamically generated plus/minus counter work independently?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In this MVC web-app the client is chosen and the user is supposed to input the information for an order on that client. The plus/minus counter is there to choose the quantity of a single product on the order.

The issue is of course that all the counters are working as one. Press one button and all the values change. I also understand why, but i do not understand how to fix it.

```
//Plus/minus counter script.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.count').prop('disabled', true);
        $(document).on('click', '.plus', function () {
            $('.count').val(parseInt($('.count').val()) + 1);
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.minus', function () {
            $('.count').val(parseInt($('.count').val()) - 1);
            if ($('.count').val() == 0) {
                $('.count').val(1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@* Template for inserting dropdowns. *@
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <div class="row-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("fromDBProducts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DBProducts"], "Velg produkt", new { @class = "form-control drop, insert-textbox" })
        @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control insert-textbox price-text", @placeholder = "kr" })
        <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
            <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
            @Html.TextBox("count", 1, new { @class = "count qty" })
            <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-btn"></button>
    </div>

</script>

@* Append and remove product-dropdown *@
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#add-product-btn').on('click', function (e) {
            $('.row-3:last').after($('#template').html());
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#remove-btn', function () {
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
        });
    });
</script>


<div class="card-container">
    <div class="card border-primary mb-3 card-client" style="max-width: 40rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Legg til ordre</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertOrder", "Add", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="row-3">
                    @Html.DropDownList("fromDBProducts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DBProducts"], "Velg produkt", new { @class = "form-control drop, insert-textbox" })
                    @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control insert-textbox price-text", @placeholder = "kr" })
                    <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                        <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                        @Html.TextBox("count", 1, new { @class = "count qty" })
                        <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-4">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="add-product-btn"></button>
                </div> 
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected result would be that the counters work independently and not as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find holder for the elements and use it to find the correct count for that plus or minus.

One way to do that is to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), but in your structure you can use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) or [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.count').prop('disabled', true);
                    $(document).on('click', '.plus', function () {
                        var count = $(this).closest(".qty").find(".count");
                        // var count = $(this).siblings(".count"); //example with siblings
                        // var count = $(this).parent().find(".count"); //example with parent
                        $(count).val(parseInt($(count).val()) + 1);
                    });
                    $(document).on('click', '.minus', function () {
                        var count = $(this).closest(".qty").find(".count");
                        // var count = $(this).siblings(".count"); //example with siblings
                        // var count = $(this).parent().find(".count"); //example with parent
                        $(count).val(parseInt($(count).val()) - 1);
                        if ($(count).val() == 0) {
                            $(count).val(1);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-3">
            <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="count" />
                <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-3">
            <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="count" />
                <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-3">
            <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="count" />
                <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-3">
            <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="count" />
                <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you want a quick explanation for different methods you can read [Subash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9193419/3768239), about similar topic