# How to append a class to table row by using parent function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append the class `red-border` to a `tr` element which contains a `span` with class `warning`. My code is not working. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css("width", "2000px");
  $(".jsgrid-table").find(".warning").parents().addClass("red-border");
});
```

```css
.red-border {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsgrid-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jsgrid-row">
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;"><span class="warning"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: .closest() is not working

Comment: `tr` elements do not support borders. You could instead put the border on the `td` based on the class on the `tr`, eg. `tr.red-border td { border: 1px solid #C00; }`

Comment: thanks for suggesting me additional information but my main problem is that it does not append class "red-border" to the tr element

Comment: `.closest() is not working` why not? how did you use it? try `$(".jsgrid-table .warning").closest("tr").addClass("red-border");`

Comment: `it does not append class "red-border" to the tr element` It does - as you can see from the snippet I edited in to your question. If it's not working for you check the console for errors and ensure you've included jQuery in the page, and are running your jQuery code after the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

adding `border` in the `tr` element is not allowed.
Also, use `.closest()` selector  to find the parent that matches the conditions

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("width", "2000px");
    $(".jsgrid-table .warning").closest("tr").addClass("red-border");
});
```

```css
.red-border{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsgrid-table">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="jsgrid-row">
   <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
   <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">
    <span class="warning"></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="jsgrid-row">
   <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As in this snippet first `tr` has class `warning` and so class `red-border` and in the next `tr` children element of this `tr` doesn't have `warning` class and no `red-border` is present in this `tr` element.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Thomas, `.closest()` is working fine. Check below the fiddle. As the borders are not supported for `tr`, I just have updated the color.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("body").css("width", "2000px");
          $(".jsgrid-table .warning").closest("tr").addClass("red-border");
     });
```

```css
.red-border{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsgrid-table">
               <tbody>
                   <tr class="jsgrid-row ">
                    <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
                    ...
                   <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;"><span class="warning"></span></td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` does not have a `border` itself, but you can make it work:

```js
$("body").css("width", "2000px");
$(".jsgrid-table .warning").closest("tr").addClass("red-border");
```

```css
tr.red-border {
  background: yellow;
}

tr.red-border > td {
  border-top: 2px dotted red;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted red;
}

tr.red-border > td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px dotted red;
}

tr.red-border > td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsgrid-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jsgrid-row">
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
      <!--...-->
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;"><span class="warning"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine except it adds the **red-border** on all parent elements. So, to add the class only on the tr tag, then pass the **tr** in the `.parents()` function.

`$(".jsgrid-table").find(".warning").parents()` --- this selects all the parent elements of the element having class **warning**

`$(".jsgrid-table").find(".warning").parents('tr')` --- this selects only **tr** element out of the all parent elements having class **warning**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css("width", "2000px");
  $(".jsgrid-table").find(".warning").parents('tr').addClass("red-border");
});
```

```css
.red-border td{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="jsgrid-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="jsgrid-row">
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;">2018</td>
      <td class="jsgrid-cell jsgrid-align-left" style="width: 100%;"><span class="warning"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**You can also check the below link for more details on parent, parents & colsest**
[Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-parents-and-closest-functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css("width", "2000px");
  $(".jsgrid-table").find(".warning").parents('tr').addClass("red-border");
});
```